# Interrupting socket.accept() by pressing key

Tags: python, windows, multithreading

I know that we can press CTRL+C to interrupt program, but when I try on program which listens on socket it is unable to do it (probably only on Windows). So I try to find the way around, but it doesn't works:

```
import sys, socket, time, msvcrt, threading

msg = ".:::SERVER:::." 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('', 8881))
s.listen(5)

def start_server():
    while True: 
        print("Waiting for connections...")
        (conn, addr) = s.accept() 
        print("Connection with:", addr[0])
        conn.send(bytes(str(len(msg)), "UTF-8"))
        conn.send(bytes(msg, "UTF-8"))
        conn.close()

t = threading.Thread(target = start_server)
t.start()

key = msvcrt.getwch()
print(key)
if key == 'z':
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Pass `daemon=True` to the `Thread` constructor to allow exiting without joining the thread.

Comment: Ctrl+C will work as long as the main thread doesn't do anything that waits without including the Windows event that Python signals for Ctrl+C. For example, `time.sleep` is fine, but not a thread `join` and not a blocking read on a socket or pipe.

Comment: Thanks, its working! but program is quitting by any keystroke. Why is that?

Comment: If you have nothing else to do in the main thread, then simply use a while loop that does `t.join(0.1)`. This blocks with a timeout and in between calls the interpreter can check for Ctrl+C.